# Python string to dict - malformed string

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to convert a string like this below to JSON or a `dict`?

```
{'action': u'delete', 'controller': u'deleteUser', 'id': u'1'}
```

I use `ast`,

```
string = {'action': u'delete', 'controller': u'deleteUser', 'id': u'1'}
print ast.literal_eval(string)
```

Error,

```
Error - <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: malformed string
```

Comment: You don't have a string. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a string it actually a dictionary. So that `literal_eval` failed to work on a dictionary.

```
string = "{'action': u'delete', 'controller': u'deleteUser', 'id': u'1'}"
print ast.literal_eval(string)
```

to get the value of `id`

```
print ast.literal_eval(string)['id']
```

Comment: so how can I access the `id` value in that `dictionary`?